# Ruby on Rails 3 Tutorial by Michael Hartl - application_helper_spec.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Inside this test file is code that looks like this:

```
        it "should include the base title" do
          full_title("foo").should =~ /^Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App/
        end
```

My question is what is "foo" doing in there?  Can it be just any string?  Because right now all my tests are passing with this "foo" parameter.

thanks,
mike

Comment: Are you sure it's not just testing that the helper adds the text?

Comment: why don't you show your full_title method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's checking that the helper method where 'foo' is passed as a parameter, returns the specified string. So, to make sure, you would need to check the full_title helper method.